# No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.pkcs11.P11Key$P11SecretKey while using SoftHSM2 AES Key

Tags: java, encryption, aes, softhsm

I'm willing to encrypt/decrypt data by using an AES Key stored in a softHSM2 software.

I'm creating my key with the following code:

```
    String configName = "C:\\SoftHSM2\\etc\\pkcs11.cfg";

    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

    Provider p = new SunPKCS11(configName);
    if (-1 == Security.addProvider(p)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("could not add security provider");
    }

    // Load the key store
    char[] pin = "123456789".toCharArray();
    keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", p);
    keyStore.load(null, pin);

    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new 
    SecretKeySpec("0123456789ABCDEF".getBytes(), "AES");
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(secretKeySpec.getEncoded(), "AES");
    keyStore.setKeyEntry("AESKey1", key, "123456789".toCharArray(), null);
    keyStore.store(null);
```

here is the pkcs11.cfg

```
name = SoftHSM2
library = c:\SoftHSM2\lib\softhsm2-x64.dll 
slotListIndex = 1
```

My Key is correctly added, here is the output:

```
AESKey1: SunPKCS11-SoftHSM2 AES secret key, 16 bits (id 4, token object, not sensitive, unextractable)
```

Now I would like to encrypt / decrypt by using this key. Here is the code to encrypt:

```
        myKey = keyStore.getKey("AESKey1", "123456789".toCharArray()); 
        System.out.println("Using key: "+myKey.toString());        
        byte[] plainTextByte = text.getBytes();                 
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myKey);
        byte[] encryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(plainTextByte);
        Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
        encryptedText = encoder.encodeToString(encryptedByte);
```

and the Decrypt function:

```
        Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
        byte[] encryptedTextByte = decoder.decode(text);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyStore.getKey("AESKey1", "1234".toCharArray())); 
        byte[] decryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextByte);
        decryptedText = new String(decryptedByte);
```

but I have the following Exception Raised:

```
Using key: SunPKCS11-SoftHSM2 AES secret key, 16 bits (id 10, token object, not sensitive, unextractable)
java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: 
sun.security.pkcs11.P11Key$P11SecretKey
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:888)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1229)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1166)

 Encrypted Text After Encryption: 
java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.pkcs11.P11Key$P11SecretKey
at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:888)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1229)
```

both cipher.init calls are raising an Exception, note that this code is working perfectly if I'm creating the AES key like this (out of the softHSM2):

```
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGenerator.init(128); // block size is 128bits
        SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
```

May be I'm missing something ?

Comment: how did you solve the issue? having the same issue right now...

Comment: well....I finally decided to go for a HSM Hardware based solution....where API provided make things much more easier...and more secure !

Answer (score 2):

You should change

```
keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", p);
```

to

```
keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
```

Regards from Italy